# Is there any command to remove characters and convert to lower case all columns?

Tags: r

For a specific column it is possible to make the following with the single commands

remove whatever is inside

```
df$test <- trimws(gsub("<.*>", "", df$test))
```

and lower case for one column

```
df$test <- lapply(dftest, \(x) trimws(tolower(x)))
```

Are there any single commands to remove characters and convert to lower case all columns from the whole data frame expect the first column?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. + how can you convert to lower case something that you've removed before? I'm not understanding correctly the steps here

Comment: Check `mutate(across(-1, function(x){...}))` from `dplyr`. The `across(-1,` means "mutate every column using the provided function, except the first".

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get the first part (I don't know what you want to remove, I agree with Mael), but for the second there's `str_to_lower` from `stringr` ([check](https://evoldyn.gitlab.io/evomics-2018/ref-sheets/R_strings.pdf))

```
  mystring <- LETTERS[1:10]
  
  library(stringr)
  
  str_to_lower(mystring)
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

Comment: For the whole dataset you could use `df %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), str_to_lower))`